# Can I initialize a variable using a custom assignment operator?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, variable-assignment

Recently I was experimenting with assignment operators in Swift and came across a problem, which I couldn't find the solution for.

Consider the following architecture:

```
struct Box<T> {

    let value: T

}

struct MyStruct {

    let myProperty: String

    init(boxedProperty: Box<String>) {
        self.myProperty = boxedProperty.value
    }

}
```

Seems pretty straightforward, but imagine that `MyStruct` accepts 20 boxed properties – each of them requires "unboxing" by accessing the `value` property of a `Box` instance. Now imagine having 20 versions of `MyStruct`.

That would lead to hundreds of `.value` lines, which is quite a lot. Instead, to reduce the code mess, I would like to use a custom assignment operator, which implicitly "unboxes" a `Box` and assigns its value to a variable.

Consider this simple example (with no optionality support, etc.):

```
infix operator <|= {
    associativity right
    precedence 90
    assignment
}

func <|= <T>(inout lhs: T, rhs: Box<T>) {
    lhs = rhs.value
}
```

Ideally, I would like to use `<|=` operator right away, like this:

```
init(boxedProperty: Box<String>) {
    self.myProperty <|= boxedProperty
}
```

But unfortunately (and quite predictably?), this doesn't work, as `myProperty` variable is not initalized before used in a function:

```
error: variable 'self.myProperty' passed by reference before being initialized
    self.myProperty <|= boxedProperty
                    ^
```

Can I ensure the compiler that my `assignment` operator function always initializes the variable (a.k.a. its `lhs` operand)? Also, if you have an idea of a different approach, feel free to comment.

---

*Note: The actual case is more complicated and requires more "unboxing" than just accessing a `value` propterty of a `Box` structure.*

Comment: Your problem is not amenable to using arrays of boxes and properties? init(boxedProperties: [Box<String>]) { self.myProperties = boxedProperties.map { %0.value } }  With this, 20 or 200 properties, no matter.

Comment: @GoZoner No. It's actually `init(anEnumValue: MyEnum)` in the real-life case. The enum value holds different associated values, which need to be double-"unboxed".

Comment: Unlike other Swift 'assignment' operators (other than actual assignment with '=') you don't need an `inout` parameter - because, as you know, you never actually reference the value.  But, on the surface you are trading off: `self.myProperty <|= boxedProperty` for `self.myProperty = boxedProperty.value`.  I don't appreciate the advantage to an operator in this case but I'm willing to admit I must not see your actual issue.

Comment: @GoZoner The real unboxing takes a couple of lines (5-10), including a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this the way you're describing, since assignment operators use both of the operands in the expression, which you can't do with an uninitialized variable. What about using a prefix operator that returns the boxed value instead?

```
prefix operator <| { }

prefix func <|<T>(rhs: Box<T>) -> T {
    return rhs.value
}

// ...

init(boxedProperty: Box<String>) {
    self.myProperty = <|boxedProperty
}
```

Comment: I thought about that too, using an infix operator just seems more natural (since I'm actually developing an open-source framework).

Comment: In that case your only way would be to give default values to all properties first, then use the infix operator to unbox / process.

Comment: Or make them optional. Nasty stuff in both cases.

Comment: I'll wait a little bit for other opinions (if any) and accept this answer if none of them meets my expectations as high as yours. :)

Comment: trips up on swift 4 - Operator should no longer be declared with body

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use syntax to accomplish your goal.  Just define a function that encapsulates your '`switch` statement with a couple of lines'.  Make sure that that function is bound with `let` so that it is accessible within `init()`  As such:

```
struct Box<T> { 
  let value: T 
  init (t:T) { 
    self.value = t 
  } 
}    

struct MyStruct { 
  let myProp: String 
  let myUnboxer : Box<String> -> String = { (b:Box<String>) in 
     /* switch, 5-10 lines */
     return b.value 
  } 

  init (bp:Box<String>) { 
    self.myProp = myUnboxer(bp) 
  } 
}
```

In action:

```
 15> var ms = MyStruct(bp:Box(t:"abc")) 
ms: MyStruct = {
  myProp = "abc"
  myUnboxer =
}
 16> ms.myProp
$R0: String = "abc"
```

The 'cost' of this is an 'extra' instance variable for `myUnboxer` but that could quickly become an advantage when the details of unboxing become structure specific - at which point you'll initialize `MyStruct` with the unboxer as well.

For me, in a language that has closures and first-class functions it is usually a mistake to invent syntax - unless one is actively defining a sublanguage.  Having statements with special evaluation rules (aka 'syntax') confuses.

Comment: It also has operators as first-class functions. ;) I think an `assignment` operator should be able to "initialize" a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have used enums to store properties of objects, like this:

```
enum TextFieldProps {
    case StringValue(String)
    case Editable(Bool)
}
```

I then have an extension to NSTextField that includes a function called `assignProps` that takes an array of `TextFieldProps`:

```
func assignProps(tfp: [TextFieldProps]) {
    tfp.reduce(self) { prop in
        switch prop {
            case .StringValue(let value):
                self.stringValue = value
            case .Editable(let value):
                self.editable = value
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

That allows me, when I need to set or change the properties of a NSTextField, to just pass an array of `TextFieldProps` to `assign`, which updates everything in one pass using `reduce`.

I take it you are trying to use something similar, only with a generic `Box` that holds the value inside of it. Perhaps there is a way to modify the technique above to suit your purposes. It is hard to give you a clear answer without knowing more about the structure of the enums and `Box`ed values that you are working with.

What I can say is that if you are trying to set the value of 20 properties, somewhere there will be 20 assignment calls, regardless of whether or not you are using a custom operator.

When I use a `Box` type object (which I sometimes do), I have a couple of different custom functions for them. One of them is just called `o`, for "open":

```
func o(b: Box<T>) -> T {
    return b.value
}

// Now you can use it like this:

init(b: Box<String>) {
    self.property = o(b)
}
```

I know it doesn't directly answer the question you asked about custom assignment operators, but if you shorten up the init label to `b` and use a function named `o`, you've gotten the whole thing down to 4 characters, `o(b)`. That's about as short and efficient as you can make it, and `o(b)`, to me, intuitively looks like shorthand for `opened box`, so the code is not too confusing.

You may want to restrict the scope of `o` so that later users of your framework can use `o` as a variable name if they want to. You can actually create `o` inside `MyStruct`'s `init` function like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let myProperty: String

    init(b: Box<String>) {
        let o: Box<String> -> String = { $0.value }
        self.myProperty = o(b)
    }
}
```

`o` is now a closure, defined inside of the `init` function and is limited in scope to just that function. You can still use `o` as a variable name anywhere else in the code that you want without any conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is solvable by using default property values.  E.g. something like:

```
struct Box<T> {

    private let value: T? = nil

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

}

struct MyStruct {

    let myProperty: String = ""

    init(boxedProperty: Box<String>) {
        self.myProperty <|= boxedProperty
    }

}

infix operator <|= { associativity right precedence 90 assignment }

func <|= <T>(inout lhs: T, rhs: Box<T>) {
    lhs = rhs.value!
}

var box = Box<String>(value: "foo")

var myStruct = MyStruct(boxedProperty: box)
```

Comment: Yes it is, but the properties shouldn't be optional.